# @OnDelete with @OneToMany only

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with annotation `@OnDelete` with `@OneToMany` relation.

```
public class Patent {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinCollumn(name = "parent_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<Child> children;

}

public class Child {
}
```

When I run it I get this error: "only inverse one-to-many associations may use `on-delete="cascade"`". How I need to change code to get it functional, without bidirectional relation? I know that, it can be solved with adding `@ManyToOne` relation, with appropriate annotations, to Child class, but I do not want to use this solution.

**Edit**: Purpose for this is that i need to generate "on delete cascade" to foreign key constraint in exported ddl schema.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use orphanRemoval parameter for your OneToMany relation. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/ for reference.

Example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", orphanRemoval="true")
public List<Order> getOrders() { ... }
```

However I think that your mapping is quite wrong, for such relation you should add Patent field to your Child class, mark relation as ManyToOne, then use JoinCollumn and set the reference as parent_id. With mappedBy and orphanRemoval options inside Patent - usability will be the same as you want.